# discover command not working in python unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am new to Python. I am trying to understand discover option python unittest module. I have written two test scripts, which contains same tests(the same file is replicated, to test discover option), whose contents are given below : .

**testFirst.py**

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def testFailure(self):

        self.assertFalse(True)

    def testError(self):
        0 / 0

    def testPass(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

import sys
sys.argv.append("-v")
unittest.main()
```

**testSecond.py**

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def testFailure(self):

        self.assertFalse(True)

    def testError(self):
        0 / 0

    def testPass(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

import sys
sys.argv.append("-v")
unittest.main()
```

**Output**

Now when I run "python -m unittest discover" command from command prompt, I get the following output :

```
testError (testFirst.Test) ... ERROR
testFailure (testFirst.Test) ... FAIL
testPass (testFirst.Test) ... ok
testError (testSecond.Test) ... ERROR
testFailure (testSecond.Test) ... FAIL
testPass (testSecond.Test) ... ok

======================================================================
ERROR: testError (testFirst.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testFirst.py", line 21, in testError
    0 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

======================================================================
ERROR: testError (testSecond.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSecond.py", line 21, in testError
    0 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

======================================================================
FAIL: testFailure (testFirst.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testFirst.py", line 18, in testFailure
    self.assertFalse(True)
AssertionError: True is not false

======================================================================
FAIL: testFailure (testSecond.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSecond.py", line 18, in testFailure
    self.assertFalse(True)
AssertionError: True is not false

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=2, errors=2)
testError (testFirst.Test) ... ERROR
testFailure (testFirst.Test) ... FAIL
testPass (testFirst.Test) ... ok
testSecond (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: testError (testFirst.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testFirst.py", line 21, in testError
    0 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

======================================================================
ERROR: testSecond (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: testSecond
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 254, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 232, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "testSecond.py", line 28, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 234, in runTests
    sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())
SystemExit: True


======================================================================
FAIL: testFailure (testFirst.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testFirst.py", line 18, in testFailure
    self.assertFalse(True)
AssertionError: True is not false

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1, errors=2)
testError (testFirst.Test) ... ERROR
testFailure (testFirst.Test) ... FAIL
testPass (testFirst.Test) ... ok
testError (testSecond.Test) ... ERROR
testFailure (testSecond.Test) ... FAIL
testPass (testSecond.Test) ... ok

======================================================================
ERROR: testError (testFirst.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testFirst.py", line 21, in testError
    0 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

======================================================================
ERROR: testError (testSecond.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSecond.py", line 21, in testError
    0 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

======================================================================
FAIL: testFailure (testFirst.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testFirst.py", line 18, in testFailure
    self.assertFalse(True)
AssertionError: True is not false

======================================================================
FAIL: testFailure (testSecond.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSecond.py", line 18, in testFailure
    self.assertFalse(True)
AssertionError: True is not false

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=2, errors=2)
testFirst (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure) ... ERROR
testError (testSecond.Test) ... ERROR
testFailure (testSecond.Test) ... FAIL
testPass (testSecond.Test) ... ok

======================================================================
ERROR: testFirst (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: testFirst
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 254, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 232, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "testFirst.py", line 28, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 234, in runTests
    sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())
SystemExit: True


======================================================================
ERROR: testError (testSecond.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSecond.py", line 21, in testError
    0 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

======================================================================
FAIL: testFailure (testSecond.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSecond.py", line 18, in testFailure
    self.assertFalse(True)
AssertionError: True is not false

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1, errors=2)
EE
======================================================================
ERROR: testFirst (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: testFirst
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 254, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 232, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "testFirst.py", line 28, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 234, in runTests
    sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())
SystemExit: True


======================================================================
ERROR: testSecond (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: testSecond
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 254, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 232, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "testSecond.py", line 28, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 234, in runTests
    sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())
SystemExit: True


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=2),
```

Which gives the impression that the tests get executed more than one time. Why is this happening? What do I do wrong?

Comment: You are calling `unittest.main()` at the end of each module.  When you use discover it imports the two modules, thus running the code in them → unit tests are executed, and then the unittest discover call executes all unit tests. That's why they run twice.

Comment: But, why am I getting absurd test counts like Ran 6 tests in 0.000s, Ran 4 tests in 0.000s, Ran 6 tests in 0.000s, Ran 4 tests in 0.000s, Ran 2 tests in 0.000s. It clearly shows that it's executing 22 test methods, while as per your comment, even if it executes each test case, total test execution must be 12, not 22, from where additional 10 methods are executed ?

Comment: what given below error mean :
ERROR: testSecond (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)

ImportError: Failed to import test module: testSecond
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 254, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 232, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "testSecond.py", line 28, in <module>
    unittest.main()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 234, in runTests
    sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())
SystemExit: True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the last 3 lines in each file and instead pass the **verbose option** `-v` when calling `unittest`, it runs the tests exactly once:

```
python -m unittest discover -v
```

Result:

```
testError (test_first.Test) ... ERROR
testFailure (test_first.Test) ... FAIL
testPass (test_first.Test) ... ok
testError (test_second.Test) ... ERROR
testFailure (test_second.Test) ... FAIL
testPass (test_second.Test) ... ok

======================================================================
ERROR: testError (test_first.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_first.py", line 9, in testError
    0 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

======================================================================
ERROR: testError (test_second.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_second.py", line 9, in testError
    0 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

======================================================================
FAIL: testFailure (test_first.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_first.py", line 6, in testFailure
    self.assertFalse(True)
AssertionError: True is not false

======================================================================
FAIL: testFailure (test_second.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_second.py", line 6, in testFailure
    self.assertFalse(True)
AssertionError: True is not false

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.004s

FAILED (failures=2, errors=2)
```